# CSS/Javascript to pull initial page (not #one)

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I have a slider. In the slider, I have 3 images. The slider rotates between images. I also have a "quicknav" set of 3 buttons. Users can click each of the 3 buttons and will be directed to the appropriate image. When an image is shown, the quicknav button changes. (e.g., when image 3 is selected, quicknav 1 and 2 will be black and quicknav 3 will be blue).

My slider works fine, except that the very first image does not have the quicknav shown when on index.html. This is because the quicknav checks "is #one, #two, #three" selected? If so, show the corresponding piece. But, when it is just index.html (which corresponds to #one), the quicknav blue is not shown.

Basically, I need to add something like the following to the code below, but I don't know the proper syntax:
.slider /:target ~ .quicknav a[href="/"]

The CSS is:

```
.slider #one:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#one"] {
    background:
        url(images/navpick1.png),
        url(images/quicknav-hover.png);
}
.slider #two:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#two"] {
    background:
        url(images/navpick2.png),
        url(images/quicknav-hover.png); 
}
.slider #three:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#three"] {
    background:
        url(images/navpick3.png),
        url(images/quicknav-hover.png); /*On current image hover for quicknav */
}
```

Here is the Javascript solution

```
//Start at #one so it looks normal
if (window.location.hash === "") {
    if (window.pageYOffset!= null){
        st=window.pageYOffset
    }
    if (document.body.scrollWidth!= null){
        st=window.pageYOffset
    }
    window.location.href = "#one";
    setTimeout('window.scrollTo(0,st)',0);
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/justin_0523/Qr2hm/3/ (I think some of the javascript isn't working on the version there, but it is fine for the actual site). I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

That was very helpful -

I added the following code to the top of the JavaScript

```
if (window.location.hash === "") {
    window.location.href = "#one";
}
```

This appears to do what you are looking to do.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkyF7/1/)

Comment: Ok, I implemented your approach. It was smart. But, it would be helpful to still learn the CSS solution, if there is one.